# Rails backend boolean toggle! not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, update-attributes, simple-form-for

I'm trying to update a boolean through an update action in Rails, though can't for the life of me get it working.

My `Users` have a `questionnaire_complete` boolean field that defaults to false. When they update their questionnaire (to submit it - it's created elsewhere) I'm telling the controller to toggle this to true, to save them being able to resubmit elsewhere.

```
def update
  if @user.form_reached # Another boolean used for path control - which works perfectly with the same toggle!
    current_user.toggle!(:questionnaire_complete) # The failing line
    SomeMailer.submission_confirmation(@user).deliver_now
    redirect_to user_answer_path(@user), notice: "Thank you for submitting your form"
  end
end
```

I know most of this is being implemented as the Mailer sends and the redirect / notice work exactly as they should. The only thing missing is (crucially) the toggle.

The form itself is a straightforward `simple_form_for @user` which updates the attributes exactly as it should.

It's just the toggle. It's killing me. Any advice warmly received :)

**UPDATE**

I've changed this to drop a hidden field into the form so I can inspect the params more closely. I've a feeling it might be as I'm also updating nested attributes in the form as the params look exactly as they should using this approach:

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |user| %>
  <%= user.input :questionnaire_complete, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => true } %>
  <%= user.simple_fields_for :user_answers do |user_answer| %>
     <li>
      <%= user_answer.text_field :answer %></br>
      </li>
  <% end %>
  <%= user.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Params:

```
"user"=>{"questionnaire_complete"=>"true", "user_answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer"=>"example", "id"=>"194"}...}
```

Comment: is there an error occurring or is the attribute field just not saving?

Comment: No errors, though nothing that seems to show in console relating to this during the patch request.... nothing that I can see that indicates why this is getting lost.

Comment: and current_user is the same user as @user? is there a reason you're using @user and current_user instead of using one

Comment: Yep, 100% the same. current_user went in as a debug - I'll swap it back for clarity's sake.

Comment: The only thing left i can think of is to check if user.valid? after the toggle or use current_user.update!(...) to make it show you an error if one is there.

Comment: Well I've got it working, though I'm afraid it wasn't through changing the code. I've restarted my comp, cleared my cookies and it's kicked into life. Thanks for all the help with this - shame to go without a clear explanation!!

Answer (score 2):

It look like you just have a typo

```
current_user.toggle!(:questionnaire_submitted)
```

in your original post you say users have a `questionaire_submitted` field but in your controller youre calling it `questionnaire_complete`

EDIT:
If it's continuing to give you a headache, you can just directly toggle the attribute yourself.

```
current_user.update(questionnaire_complete: !current_user.questionaire_complete)
```

In fact, I'd recommend this since it appears [`#toggle!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle!) skips validations. although it's also noteworthy that since you're toggling this, if the user enters this route again (and `form_reached` is true), you'll be setting `questionnaire_complete` to false, which (without any additional information of what you're trying to accomplish) seems an odd thing to do (as opposed to just setting it to true).

Comment: Ah - good spot. Unfortunately just a typo in this question and not the solution to my woes. Thanks @PhilVarg

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, nothing has seemed to work though - setting this as you've suggested in the edit, `update_attributes(questionnaire_complete: true)`, setting it in the view as a hack.... I've added an edit above though - do you think the nested attributes could be an issue?

Comment: Oh and the page can't be visited once questionnaire_complete is true, so the validations aren't an issue here

Comment: I didnt mean to set update_attributes in the view or the edit route, i meant replacing toggle with update_attributes in the update route.